# curl Authentication error on Images Only

Tags: php, http-status-code-401, php-curl

I am trying to get information from a XML Rest API.

I can get everything but not the images.

**I can display all info, but when it comes on images I get 401 error**

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()`.

My username and password are correct. The only way to get the images display is if I login to this API in a different window. Then all images are displayed.

Am I doing something wrong ? Here is my php code:

```
function CallAPI($url){
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "usr:psw");
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
}

$a = "query SQL";
$asd = $database->query($a);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($asd)){
    echo $url = $row['url']; // I can get this data display
    $row['hotel_name'];
    $a = CallAPI($url);
    $axml = new SimpleXMLElement($a);
    $img_link = $axml->item->images;
    foreach ($img_link->image as $value) {
        echo "<img src='".$value->sizes->size[1]->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')."' class='img-responsive' />"; 
    }
```

Comment: In the line `$a = CallAPI($url);` your backend server reads the data. But when it comes to images, you are only generating IMG tags. That means that the server is not fetching the images, but a webbrowser. And probably the browser does not have permissions to fetch those images.

Comment: @JustAC0der if I open a new window and login in that api I can display the images. But when send my user-pass through curl i can access everything in API except of images

Comment: I am guessing, but it seems that you need two PHP scripts: one for fetching the main data (from `$row['url']`) and another one for fetching images (let's say we call it `fetch_images.php`). And you need to link from the first one to the second one, eg. `'<img src="/fetch_images.php?url=' . urlencode($value->sizes->size[1]->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')) . '">'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem must be that this link need authentication as well. So try make the call for `$value->sizes->size[1]->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')` to pass user and pass.

So you code should look like this

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($asd)){
$url = $row['url'];
$row['hotel_name']; // No use of this one, maybe you use it on your end
$a = CallAPI($url);
$axml = new SimpleXMLElement($a);
$img_link = $axml->item->images;
foreach ($img_link->image as $value) {
    /*I am adding the link to a variable*/
    $imgLinkFromValue = $value->sizes->size[1]->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
    $img = CallAPI($imgLinkFromValue );
    /* Now if you still get a link just pass the variable */
    echo "<img src='$img->**link or href or anything you get**' class='img-responsive' />"; 
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you getting text or symbols maybe you have to use `base64_encode()`.

Try this :

`$img = base64_encode(CallAPI($imgLinkFromValue ));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $img . '" class="img-responsive" />'`

You can always change the data inside src to png or gif, depends on what you need.

For more Info about base64_encode function you can use this link.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: Thanks for you answer but if I use CallAPI I cant get the image I get a wierd string and some symbols instead of the image